# Facebook like button unlike itself

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I added facebook like button on my site. Everything is working fine two days before but now I m getting error when I clicked like button it gets liked and after 2-3 seconds it unlikes itself automatically. After finding on net I found facebook linter tool but problem is that when I put page's url in it and run it, that page's like button starts working fine. So what's wrong with my site why this is happening and what linter tool do. Please help me.

This is the code that I used:

`<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php $pageurl ?>&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=80&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:80px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>`

In above code $pageurl is changes according to page.

Thanks......

Comment: Me also felt the same issue yesterday in my project. May be some issue with facebook

Comment: @user392406 is `$pageurl` urlencoded?

Comment: yes. I used urlencoded url but still like button automatically unlikes itself.

Comment: When I use facebook linter tool to debug url it shows warning as Required Property Missing og:title is required
Required Property Missing og:type is required
Required Property Missing og:url is required. Is it necessary to add these meta tags in head section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is perfect but there is problem on Facebook's end. I faced the same problem, this solution worked for me - [**FIX: Facebook Like Button Unlikes Itself**](http://www.techblogx.com/facebook-like-button-not-working-solution.html).

Answer (score 2):

Man I was trying to figure this out till 3am last night, because none of the solutions worked :/ ... it ended up working for me by changing 1 minor setting.

Solution: Try using the "Live feed" app ID rather than the default "Live Stream" when you're getting your code from the facebook developers page.

Answer (score 1):

Running the page through the linter is not a good solution in this person's case since the URL changes.  I for example have thousands of articles on my site.  The URL contains an article ID.  There is now way I am going manually feed each of these pages through the Facebook linter.

There needs to be a better fix.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy fix for any page that has a broken facebook button that unlikes itself when clicked.  Just copy the URL of your page and enter it in the Facebook LINTER tool here:

Facebook LINTER -> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint

I'm not sure of the exact details of why this works, but from what I've been able to gather, when you run the LINTER tool on your URL it will also update the cache facebook has for your URL.  The error with the button working is on the facebook side, so by running this tool and getting facebook to update their cached data for your page, the like button starts working again.  I've seen this broken facebook button occur for a few different reasons, one being that a page used to use the old facebook share button.  When you add the new like button to a page that used to use a share button, the like button won't work until you run the page through the linter.

Bottom line is doing this will fix your like button.  If your facebook button doesn't work on a page, run it through the LINTER tool.  Hope this helps!